# Colspans in Opera Browsers not working right

Tags: html, html-table, opera

I can't understand the problem here but this looks fine in all browsers cept Opera.

The HTML Code is as follows:

```
<table width="395" height="214" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Here is some content in here that has 2 colspans</td>
    <td width="137">This only has 1 colspan.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="113">This has only 1 colspan also.</td>
    <td colspan="2">This cell has 2 colspans now and should look presentable hopefully.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">This cell has 3 colspans within this table and should fill up the entire width of the table.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now the Output looks like this in Opera:

[image]

But how do I make it look like this (as all other browsers look like):
[image]

The problem is actually much deeper than this, but this is the main basic overall problem.

Comment: Does it help if you explicitly specify `colspan = "1"` for the other cells?

Comment: No, this makes no difference, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I would try giving explicit css classes with explicit widths to *every* td.

`<td class="foo">`

`.foo { width:200px; }`.

Make sure the math adds up properly.

Answer (score 1):

This bug exists in Opera 9, 10, 11 and 12.

Opera counts the number of columns as the maximum number of `<td>` or `<th>` tags in a row. This means you always need one row with all tds having no colspan attribute or the colspan attribute set to 1. Adding table-layout: fixed to the table style seems to help as well.

This bug is fixed since Opera switched from the Presto to the Blink rendering engine in 2013.

http://www.crydust.be/test/opera_table_colspan_bug/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug :-/ I've found your bug report, thanks. I guess you need a hack where you add one row that has the total expected number of cells and style it to be invisible.. :-(

Comment: Seems a bit sloppy to add a <tr> element at the beginning of the table that has all of the <td> elements in it with their proper widths if you ask me.  Opera needs to support this.  I understand Opera is not as old as some of these other browsers, but they need to get with the program if you ask me!!